# What are the suitable options for lightweight RUDP network library for c++ and mono?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, networking, zeromq, enet

It's a long time that I'm prototyping the network libraries for our MMO game which it's back-end is in c++ and the client uses Unity3d.

- I've used ZeroMQ, It's a very strong and awesome library but it doesn't have an official port for c# with .Net 3.5, So I can not use it with unity properly in the client and it also does not have the RUDP support.
- I've checked ENet, It's basically an RUDP messaging library, but I couldn't find any proper working port for Mono.
- I checked Hazel Networking library which has been developed to be used with Unity, but it doesn't have a native c++ port.
- I've checked lot's of other messaging libraries, all of them didn't support RUDP or they didn't have the library in both languages.

Does anybody know about a library which fulfills my requirements?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic for SO. Please try the [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead. Avoid cross posting.

Comment: @Ron while one may feel right in re-articulating S/O rules, Farzam has explicitly expressed a reasonable amount of both research and problem-formulation efforts, so kindly revise the expressed will to punish his step towards merit-focused Community. There are much wilder / poorer posts that deserve administrative help of this sort. It is so easy to punish and it is so seldom to develop better Community practices in niche segments ( compared to heaps of posts in mainstream topics ). Do not judge without a due consideration what does step create new and better for highly specialised subcultures.

Comment: @user3666197 Well researched or not the question states: "_Does anybody know about a library which fulfills my requirements?_" That is asking for library recommendations thus making it off-topic for SO. Your assumption of me "_expressing the will to punish his step towards merit-focused Community_" is wrong to say the least. The question is ideal for Software Recs.

Comment: @user3666197 Unfortunately, library recommendations tend to not work well on Stack Overflow, so they're disallowed.  This question is a much better fit for Software Recommendations, as Ron pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

### Reliable?

Well, **reliable** is a word that [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) evangelisation from Pieter HINTJENS explains not to ever expect granted from a transport-class per-se, but rather get it built ad-hoc, by a problem-domain specific smart using of the tools provided by any signalling / messaging framework.

### Integration issues?

If I were in your shoes, and having for years my hands dirty with ZeroMQ v2.1.1 -- right due to cross-compatibility issues in heterogeneous uncontrollable code-execution environment -- I would investigate what POSIX-compliant `nanomsg` can bring to the table ( C-based, C++ & .NET bindings ready ) and indeed a very lightweight tool.

Comment: Hi user3666197, me again! Please don't add meta commentary to your posts. I am aware you don't like close votes, but it is the community's view that they are the correct way to operate this site. Please respect that, even if you disagree.